# runtime Error 438

Tags: vba, runtime-error, copy-paste

I just started VBA and I am trying to copy the content of an active cell and past it to another column of the same page. But it keeps giving me run time error. Any suggestion would be helpful.

```
Option Explicit
Sub copypaste()

Dim lastrow As Long, content As String, i As Integer, numrow As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
numrow = ActiveCell.Row

content = ActiveCell.Value

For i = 0 To (lastrow - numrow)

If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(numrow + i, 1).Value = content Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(numrow + i, 2).copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2+i, 10).Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If

Next i
End Sub
```

The runtime error given is object doesnt support this property or method. Any suggestion will help! Thanks

Comment: Always point out what line of code is giving you the error. Helps us figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the value of one cell to another instead of copying

```
Option Explicit
Sub copypaste()

Dim lastrow As Long, content As String, i As Integer, numrow As Integer

lastrow = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
numrow = ActiveCell.Row

content = ActiveCell.Value

For i = 0 To (lastrow - numrow)

If Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(numrow + i, 1).Value = content Then
Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2+i, 10).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(numrow + i, 2).Value
End If

Next i
End Sub
```